# Integration test methods in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have problem with integration test cause one element dosen't work. When I add

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, response.getBody(),false);
```

I have red erro and information: Unhandled Exception: org.json.JSONException.
I show U all my integration test code :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TeamService.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TeamIntegrationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    @Test
    public void integrationTeamTest(){

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(null,headers);

        HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                createURLWithPort("/teams"),
                HttpMethod.GET,entity,String.class);

        String expected = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Apacze\",\"description\":\"grupa programistow\",\"city\":\"Włocławek\",\"headcount\":null},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Apacze\",\"description\":\"grupa programistow\",\"city\":\"Radom\",\"headcount\":null},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Apacze\",\"description\":\"grupa programistow\",\"city\":\"Warszawa\",\"headcount\":null},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Apacze\",\"description\":\"grupa programistow\",\"city\":\"Kraków\",\"headcount\":null}";

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, response.getBody(),false); -> this line throw exception
    }

    private String createURLWithPort(String uri){
        return "http://localhost:" + port + uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the stacktrace, or indicate which line you are getting the exception at.

Comment: Is this during compile time or run time?

Comment: might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130285/unhandled-exception-org-json-jsonexception